# Connect to people api account via AccountManager android

Tags: android

I can get an access token through the AccountManager, but what should I do next to connect to people API?

Answer (score 0):

All good, if i have token i can access to any google api,
token=String
`

```
HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
try {
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);
    PeopleService service=new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, 
    JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
    ListConnectionsResponse response = service.people().connections()
        .list("people/me")
        .setPageSize(10)
        .setPersonFields("names, emailAddresses")
        .execute();
List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();
for(int i=0;i<response.size();i++)
    for(int j=0;j<connections.size();j++)
        System.out.println(connections.get(j));
```

`